# How to Get Node Name and child names from xml using lambda expression asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am new to Lambda expression here i have xml format below like this

```
<authorofBook>
<chycology category="New">
<Book id"1">professor cesior</Book>
<Book id"2">professor cesior</Book>
<Book id"3">professor cesior</Book>
</chycology>
<chycology category="Old">
<Book id"1"> willom</Book>
<Book id"2">taylor</Book>
</chycology>
<authorofBook>
```

so i need to get and Bind to to drop down like Old One and New Books separately how to bind

i had done Like this

```
document.Descendants("authorofBook").Descendants("chycology")
    .Where(g => g.Attribute("category").Value == "category")
    .Select(g => new Author
        {
            Authortype="New",
            BookId =g.Elements("chycology").Select(x=>x.Attribute("Id").Value).ToList(),
            catogory= g.Elements("chycology").Select(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value).ToList() : null,

        }).ToList());
```

but i don't know how to get the Books based on category

Comment: It is not quite clear from your code - what result are  you expecting. What is `Author` class and its fields? How your xml should be translated to list of Authors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;

        XElement books= doc.Descendants(ns + "chycology").First(x => x.Attribute("category").Value.Equals("New"));
```

Maybe you can try something like this? This is how I do it in my project.

Edit without namespace

```
      XElement books= doc.Descendants("chycology").First(x => x.Attribute("category").Value
```

Comment: As far as I can see - OP's xml doesn't contains namespaces. So why bothering about it?

Comment: it's working fine cant we get the Both Old and new books in List if so can u guide me to get Both Books it's and name please

Comment: Yeah Andy, you're right, I just thought I would include it for others

Comment: If you want them both, you should just use this: 
`XElement books= doc.Descendants(ns + "chycology");` 
I looped over the elements and assigned the value to a list.

 `foreach (XElement book in books)
            {
                bookList.Add(book.Value.ToString());
            }`

Hope this helps you

Comment: Or without namespace: 

`XElement books= doc.Descendants("chycology");`



`foreach (XElement book in books) { bookList.Add(book.Value.ToString()); } `